# Best way to implement object container in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab, oop, iterator

I am using object-oriented Matlab, and I wonder, what would be the best way to make a list of objects, all instances of the same class? I want to be able to iterate over the list in a for-loop and access the same functions for each instance of my class.

Comment: what's wrong with a simple array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reiterate what [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318415/best-way-to-implement-object-container-in-matlab#comment25118937_17318415) mentioned in the comments, MATLAB [supports](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-arrays.html) creating an array of objects, assuming they are all of the same class (and that cat/horzcat/vertcat methods are not explicitly overriden otherwise). For example:

```
obj = MyClass();
arr = [obj,obj];    %# 1x2 array of objects
for ii=1:numel(arr)
    arr(ii)
end
```

It is even possible to create arrays of objects of [different types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/concatenating-objects-of-different-classes.html) by implementing converters method or having all your classes inherit from [matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneousclass.html) superclass.